# How much memory does null pointer use?

Tags: c#, memory, reference, memory-management

In C# if i use the following code

```
Dictionary<int,object> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, object>();
dictionary.Add(1,null);
dictionary.Add(2,new object());
dictionary[2] = null;
```

How much memory is being allocated?
does each object reference in the dictionary (dictionary[1], dictionary[2]) takes a pointer size (32 or 64 bit) on the heap? in other words when i do dictionary.Add(1,null) does the CLR automatically create 2 allocations on the heap, one for the int and one for a null pointer?

Answer (score 17):

The null pointer does not allocate any extra memory to store anything on the heap (since there is nothing to store). However, your dictionary has to store the null pointer itself, which takes just as much space as any other pointer.

Whether every add call results in new allocations (to store the pointer) or not depends on the Dictionary implementation. Usually, it has an internal array which gets re-sized as necessary.

In your example, I would assume that enough space for a few elements is already allocated when you create the dictionary. So the add(1, null) will not allocate any more space.

Update: The [default initial capacity for Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760931/initial-capacity-of-collection-types-i-e-dictionary-list) is not specified. In .NET 4.0, it starts out at 0, actually, so the first add will create the storage array.

Comment: Great answer thanks! I am learning linked lists -- how does the system handle the fact that a linked list creates an infinite amount of null pointers? They are not all used, obviously, but the creation of the node struct with data and a node pointer recursively creates pointer nodes. How is this handled in memory? Every null pointer has a memory address? Do computers dynamically allocate that memory as needed?

Answer (score 3):

In itself a null pointer will take up 4 or 8 bytes, depending on whether it is running as 32-bit or 64-bit, as you've surmised.

There can be more than this in a given collection. The implementation of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` uses both an array of `Entry<TKey, TValue>` structures, which contains two `int`s as well as the key and value, and also an array of integers used in indexing into that array. Hence even if there was no "growing room" (and there generally is) each entry would need 20bytes or 24bytes of memory (rather than just the 8 or 12 entailed by the size of the key and value), on top of the overhead for the dictionary itself (including the overhead of each array).

Other implementations and other collections will have other overheads. They may not even store a `null` for a null entry. `null` can be a useful way of indicating a value has not been written in which case a special value will indicate an actual value of `null` (particularly useful in lock-free dictionary implementations, where it can be useful to distinguish between not just an unset and set value, but between an unset, set, and partially set value).

All you can really say is that setting adding a value of `null` A) takes up some memory and B) does not take up the memory that with a non-null value would be taken up by the object itself. Even B) doesn't really hold, since if that object was also stored elsewhere, then there's no extra memory cost in having another reference elsewhere, beyond that of the reference itself, which makes the real cost of it the same as storing `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess yes, because null is an reference. It's points to nowhere, but you can replace it every time with a real object reference.

So I guess that at least 2x64bit are allocated, maybe the Dictionary needs additional space for itself.

Comment: I agree with ur answer, but I have a question about this. pointers are int32 or int64 variables, so, even if u set them null, we have no other object in memory but still have int32 objects as pointer variables yes?

Comment: @ Dr TJ: Pointers are not actually int32 or int64 objects, but they do have the same size. Cf. Double has the same size as an int64, but is a different type. The null pointer is represented by 32 or 64 zero bits, and those bits obviously have to be stored somewhere.