# What is the default capacity of Stack object?

Tags: c#, .net

What is the default capacity of `Stack` object?
I heard it is 10, but I can't find it on MSDN. See this [google book.](https://books.google.com/books?id=XimWpv-_iw4C&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=initial%20capacity%20of%20stack%20object&source=bl&ots=Jc8gMMJB2d&sig=astxBkmSN-mPICQVpz-znbJt3Zs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8-vQVKSfENLGsQS_44HgBg&ved=0CEQQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=initial%20capacity%20of%20stack%20object&f=false)

Also I am practicing a certification test by a software. It has the same result. See the image.

[image: test]

But I found some [interesting answers which are different.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760931/initial-capacity-of-collection-types-e-g-dictionary-list)

Comment: Don't make me have to zoom to see question content. It's an image of text - why not just include the text? Is the image even necessary for this question?

Comment: The software prevents me to copy and paste as its copyright. Sorry about it.

Comment: So... Because it is copyright you thought you would screen grab and share... Sure that won't breach copyright... Much...

Comment: Just a partial, I guess that it should be okay.

Comment: So, if you copy-pasted the same part of it...

Comment: That... is a rubbish test.

Comment: You should never care what the default capacity is.  It is abstracted away from you *by design*, and it's an implementation detail that's subject to change anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the current source code it says 10 also.

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/stack.cs,7c1d0a7ea96800a3,references

Comment: Interestingly, if you instatiate the `Stack` with a null `ICollection` , the size is set to 32 rather than the default.

Answer (score 6):

Default capacity of `System.Collection.Stack` is 10.

Default capacity of `System.Collection.Generic.Stack<T>` is 0.

You can see it by yourself just in source codes:

- [`Stack`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/stack.cs,6acda10c5f8b128e)
- [`Stack<T>`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/stack.cs,c5371bef044c6ab6)

All of above is about current .NET implementation and may be changed in future.

Answer (score 3):

In C#, a `Stack<T>` starts out with a capacity of 0 (it holds an empty array), then when you add an item, the capacity will be 4. After that, if the array is full when you add an item, it will double in size.

You can see for yourself in the source: [Stack](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/stack.cs,c5371bef044c6ab6)

You mentioned 10. I think In Java, the capacity for collections starts at 10.

Comment: `Every time the inner array is full, it will double in size` - no, every time the inner array is full *and another element is pushed*.

Comment: Eh, fair enough, I guess the "when you add an item" carries over :p

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to see it:

```
var stack = new Stack();
var fieldInfo = typeof(Stack).GetField("_array", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
Console.WriteLine((fieldInfo.GetValue(stack) as object[]).Length); // 10

var genericStack = new Stack<int>();
var genericFieldInfo = typeof(Stack<int>).GetField("_array", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
Console.WriteLine((genericFieldInfo.GetValue(genericStack) as int[]).Length); // 0
```