# Retrieve an object from hashset in C#

Tags: c#, hash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I retrieve an item from a HashSet without enumeration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494812/why-cant-i-retrieve-an-item-from-a-hashset-without-enumeration)

I need to add a lot of objects to a Set.and I should retrieve them very fast. The only way that I know is using hash. But the HashSet class in C# doesn't contain any 'Get' method. The dictionary class isn't useful because Finding an object is very time-consuming in a dictionary.

Comment: This might help in future:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229335(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @Masoud: Can you publish your code? Might be easier to reconstruct :-)

Comment: The hash returned by `GetHashCode` isn't unique, so what you're trying to do doesn't make much sense.

Comment: My question is simple. I just want to add an object to a set and retrieve it very fast.

Comment: Why are you using a hashset? Why not use a dictionary? Dictionary is fast. Or you can use Hashtable.

Comment: It really sounds like you actually want `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` here

Comment: I used dictionary but it is the most time consuming retrieving I ever seen. A real hash should be able to retrieve data in O(1)

Comment: Possible answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869452/a-faster-replacement-to-the-dictionarytkey-tvalue

Comment: @Masoud, how did you reach the conclusion that the Dictionary<TKey, TValue> is time consuming and not retrieving data in O(1)?

Answer (score 14):

HashSets are basically used to test if an object is included in the collection. It is un-orderd and un-sorted, doesnt have an index that could be used to retrive an object.

If you need to store and retrieve objects, use other collection types like List, HashTable etc.

Comment: I am sorry, I dont understand. Here is how you can use a HashTable. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309357

Comment: There is a Hashtable class in System.Collections.Hashtable. http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx

Comment: The (generic) hashtable class is called `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`.

Comment: hashtable hsa no get method same as hashset. dictionary is too slow. I need a real hash that can retrieve added datas very fast.

Comment: @Masoud I would recommend that you share the exact scenario that you want to implement. That way we would be able to help you better.

Comment: You can store your data in the keys of a Dictionary. The values can be anything (don't care). For example booleans which are all 'true'. Finding your data will then be quick - O(1).

Comment: @oferei that does not work as there is still no way to access the existing Dictionary key using your 'equivalent' key. You need to use a Dictionary where the key and value are the same.

Answer (score 1):

The HashSet represents a number of values. You can look if a certain value is in the set by using `Contains()`. A Dictionary is for storing objects and retrieving it by its hash (key).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public enum EnumA
        {
            One,
            Two,
            Three,
            Four
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HashSet<EnumA> test = new HashSet<EnumA>();

            test.Add(EnumA.Four);

            Console.WriteLine("Contains one:");
            Console.WriteLine(test.Contains(EnumA.One));
            Console.WriteLine("Contains four:");
            Console.WriteLine(test.Contains(EnumA.Four));
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();

            return;
        }
    }
}
```